# Mi bucle do-while rompe el ciclo cuando no tiene que hacerlo

Tags: c++, bucles

mi bucle do-while rompe todo el ciclo cuando en realidad no tiene que hacerlo, no entiendo por que lo hace, a continuación dejo el código:

```
do{
        cout<<"Desea registrar OTRO zapato S/N: "; cin>>registro;
        if(registro == 'n' || 'N'){
            cout<<"\nFIN DE LA APLICACION "<<endl<<endl;
            cout<<"Nombre: Jose Erasmo Hernandez Yate";
            break;
        }
        else(registro == 's' || 'S');{
            cout<<"Digite la referencia: "; cin>>referencia;
            cout<<"Digite una descripcion: "; cin.ignore(); cin.getline(descripcion, 30);
            cout<<"Digite la talla: "; cin>>talla;
            cout<<"Costo: "; cin>>costo;
            cout<<endl;
        }
    }while(registro == 's');
```

Comment: Error en `else(registro == 's' || 'S');` sobra el **;**

Comment: hola amigo @quevedo, ya actualice el codigo, pasa que sigue con el error debido que no rompe el ciclo cuando tiene que hacerlo, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema radica que no estás escribiendo la condición de forma correcta:

```c
if(registro == 'n' || 'N')
```

Como verás, el código es equivalente a:

```c
if(registro == 'n' || 'N' != 0)
```

Por lo tanto, el resultado de toda esa condición **siempre** sera `true` y lo demostramos de esta manera:

```c
char ch = 'N';
if(ch) //Equivalente a (ch != 0)
{
    cout << "Hello";
}
```

La condición **siempre** dara `true`. Ahora, si tuviéramos esto:

```c
if(0) //Equivalente a (0 != 0)
{
    cout << "Hello";
}
```

La condición **siempre** dara `false`.

Entonces, esa es la razón del porque el bucle siempre se rompe.

**Solución:** Debemos especificar la condición de esta manera:

```c
if(registro == 'n' || registro == 'N')
```

Otra falla que noté en el código, es lo siguiente:

```c
else(registro == 's' || 'S');
```

El código debería ser cambiado a:

```c
else if(registro == 's' || registro == 'S')
```

**Nota:** El `else` que está antes del `if` es innecesario y no hace falta porque en el código de la condición de arriba ya tiene un `break;`.

Siguiendo con las correcciones, el código quedaría así:

```c
do
{
    cout<<"Desea registrar OTRO zapato S/N: "; 
    cin>>registro;
    if(registro == 'n' || registro == 'N')
    {
        cout<<"\nFIN DE LA APLICACION "<<endl<<endl;
        cout<<"Nombre: Jose Erasmo Hernandez Yate";
        break;
    }
    else if(registro == 's' || registro == 'S')
    {
        cout<<"Digite la referencia: "; 
        cin>>referencia;
        cout<<"Digite una descripcion: "; 
        cin.ignore(); 
        cin.getline(descripcion, 30);
        cout<<"Digite la talla: "; 
        cin>>talla;
        cout<<"Costo: "; 
        cin>>costo;
        cout<<endl;
    }
}while(registro == 's' || registro == 'S');
```

De igual manera, también se podría agregar un caso contrario cuando no ingrese la opción correcta:

```c
do
{
    cout<<"Desea registrar OTRO zapato S/N: "; 
    cin>>registro;
    if(registro == 'n' || registro == 'N')
    {
        cout<<"\nFIN DE LA APLICACION "<<endl<<endl;
        cout<<"Nombre: Jose Erasmo Hernandez Yate";
        break;
    }
    else if(registro == 's' || registro == 'S')
    {
        cout<<"Digite la referencia: "; 
        cin>>referencia;
        cout<<"Digite una descripcion: "; 
        cin.ignore(); 
        cin.getline(descripcion, 30);
        cout<<"Digite la talla: "; 
        cin>>talla;
        cout<<"Costo: "; 
        cin>>costo;
        cout<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        registro = 's';
        cout << "Opcion incorrecta, ingrese S/N";
    }
}while(registro == 's' || registro == 'S');
```

Comment: muchas gracias amigo, muy buen consejo.

Answer (score 1):

Hace mucho que no programo en C++ así que no estoy al tanto de la nueva sintaxis pero definitivamente te sobra un punto y coma después del else. Además no se escribe más de una sentencia por línea (aunque al compilador no le importa eso). Y se dejan espacios para mejor legibilidad.

```
char registro;
do {
    cout << "Desea registrar OTRO zapato S/N: ";
    cin >> registro;
    registro := tolower(registro);
    if (registro == 'n') {
        cout << "\nFIN DE LA APLICACION " << endl << endl;
        cout << "Nombre: Jose Erasmo Hernandez Yate";
    }
    else if (registro == 's') {
        cout << "Digite la referencia: ";
        cin >> referencia;
        cout << "Digite una descripcion: "; 
        cin.ignore();
        cin.getline(descripcion, 30);
        cout << "Digite la talla: ";
        cin >> talla;
        cout << "Costo: ";
        cin >> costo;
        cout << endl;
    }
} while(registro == 's');
```

Comment: hola amigo @drkblog, ya actualice el codigo como tu lo pusiste, pasa que sigue con el error debido que no rompe el ciclo cuando tiene que hacerlo, muchas gracias.

Comment: Ahí le corregí un error más y lo simplifiqué. Estaría bueno que aclares qué considerás correcto. Ya que lo que se puede suponer es que cuando el usuario ingresa 'N' el bucle corta. Pero por ahí tenés una idea distinta.

Comment: @JoséHernández podrias aclarar cual es el error que encuentras, es decir cual es especificamente el comportamiento no esperado

Comment: ya pude resolver el problema, muchas gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 1):

Según la sintaxis de C++ que conozco la condición esta mal puesta pues el || esta evaluando mal así como esta puesto. Por otro lado no se esta considerando cuando el usuario no introduce ni '**n**' ni '**s**'.
Te propongo lo siguiente:

```
do{
      cout<<"Desea registrar OTRO zapato S/N: "; cin>>registro;
        if(registro == 'n' || registro == 'N'){
        registro = 'n';
            cout<<"\nFIN DE LA APLICACION "<<endl<<endl;
            cout<<"Nombre: Jose Erasmo Hernandez Yate";
            break;
        }else{
        if(registro == 's' || registro == 'S'){
            cout<<"Digite la referencia: "; cin>>referencia;
            cout<<"Digite una descripcion: "; cin.ignore(); cin.getline(descripcion, 30);
            cout<<"Digite la talla: "; cin>>talla;
            cout<<"Costo: "; cin>>costo;
            cout<<endl;
        }else{
        cout<<"Opcion no valida"<<endl;
        
    }

    }
    }while(registro != 'n');

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

ten en cuenta que según tu código inicial la declaración `else` solo realiza el procedimiento en caso no se cumpla lo señalado en la sentencia `if`, si deseas hacer una validación adicional te recomiendo usar `else if`, asimismo adicione `tolower` para evitar inconvenientes al ingresar S/N en mayusculas-

```
do{
    cout<<"Desea registrar OTRO zapato S/N: ";
    cin>>registro;
    registro = tolower(registro);
    if(registro == 'n'){
        cout<<"\nFIN DE LA APLICACION "<<endl<<endl;
        cout<<"Nombre: Jose Erasmo Hernandez Yate";
        break;
    }
    else if(registro == 's'){
        cout<<"Digite la referencia: "; 
        cin>>referencia;
        cout<<"Digite una descripcion: "; 
        cin.ignore(); 
        cin >> descripcion;
        cout<<"Digite la talla: "; 
        cin>>talla;
        cout<<"Costo: "; 
        cin>>costo;
        cout<<endl;
    }
}while(registro != 's');
```

Comment: no sabia que el else solo se ejecuta  en caso de que no se realice la comparación indicada en el if, muchas gracias.